# Filtro Mysql com ORDER BY

Tags: php

Eu tenho uma linha para filtrar alguns valores:

Level
Exp
Kills
playtime

```
if (
  $cron_6 = mysqli_query(server_player(),
    "SELECT 
       player.id,
       player.name,
       player.level, 
       player.job,
       player_index.empire,
       player.exp,
     IF NULL(player.quantidade,0) 
       as 
         kills, 
         player.quantidade 
     FROM 
         player 
     LEFT JOIN 
         player_index 
     ON 
         player_index.id = player.account_id 
     LEFT JOIN 
         kill_system 
     ON 
         player.id = kill_system.id 
     WHERE 
         player.name 
           NOT LIKE 
             '[%]%' 
           OR 
             player.name 
           LIKE 
             '%[VIP]%' 
     ORDER BY 
         player.level 
           DESC, 
         quantidade 
           DESC, 
         player.playtime 
           DESC, 
         player.exp 
           DESC
      ;"
    )
  );
```

No caso o valor seria (ranking):

> top kill (quem tem mais kill)
>
> top level (quem tem mais level)
>
> top exp (quem tem mais exp)
>
> top playtime (quem tem mais tempo)

O meu site com o ranking: https://sowmt2.org/site/ranking/players

No caso quem tem +kill deveria ficar em primeiro.

Answer (score 0):

Só adicionar o kills no order by. [SQL ORDER BY Keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

Pelo jeito que você escreveu, ficaria assim:

`ORDER BY kills DESC, player.level DESC, player.exp DESC`

Comment: Por incrivel que pareça eu já fiz isso mesmo assim os dados "kills" não ficam ordenados.

Comment: no caso o quantidade DESC, já representa os kills entendeu.